# PS1 under term and shell doesn't match system

Tags: term, prompt

I find under both shells and terms in Emacs my prompt does not appear as I would expect based on my `$PS1` appears as...

```
# Shell under Emacs
]0;slackline@583.datascience.work.com: /home/slackline@samba.sheffield.work.comslackline@583 ~ $ echo PS1
\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\]

# Terminal under Emacs
0;slackline@583.datascience.work.com: /home/slackline@samba.sheffield.work.comslackline@583 ~ $ echo PS1
\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\]

# GNOME or xfce4 Terminal 
slackline@583 ~/ $ echo PS1
\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\]
```

I set `$PS1` in `~/.bashrc` so that its sourced each time a shell is started (rather than login)...

```
$ grep PS1 ~/.bashrc
export PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\] '
```

I found [this thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12337/why-does-the-emacs-ansi-term-and-emacs-shell-ps1-prompt-not-match-my-system-ps1) which suggests its a down to differences between login and non-login shells and whether PS1 is being sourced from `/etc/profile` or a user-config, and suggests that under Emacs since its non-login its user configs that are used first.  Checking `/etc/profile` to rule it out it has the following...

```
$ grep PS1 /etc/profile
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
      PS1='# '
      PS1='$ '
```

...what is strange to me (if I've understood it correctly) is that `\h:\w` is commented out in this file and based on the above linked thread shouldn't be being sourced, yet it appears that this is what is being pre-pended to the prompt I would expect to see.

EDIT : [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89054/emacs-shell-mode-makes-ps1-different) looks like a partial solution although I've given it a whirl and doesn't appear to have worked, will try again though.

EDIT2 : Found a solution to this problem and its down to how [PROMPT_COMMAND is set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39496135/1444043)...

```
if [ -z "$INSIDE_EMACS" ];
    then
    export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'                       |                                                                                                         
else                                                                                                  
    export PROMPT_COMMAND=''                                                                           
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `$PS1` *does match*: your echo statements in the first example return identical results. I think the problem is that the escape codes aren't getting processed properly. I use the following in my config:

```
;; translate control sequences as text is inserted in shell mode
(add-to-list 'comint-output-filter-functions 'ansi-color-process-output)

;; turn on color code support in shell mode
(ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
```

I don't use term, but it should be configurable as well.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this @Tyler I'll have a play around with your solution at some point, with the method of removing PROMPT_COMMAND under Emacs Terms/shells I still have colour prompts at present, but your proposal sounds useful to protect against problems in the future.